# RegEx for finding number after back slash double quotation colon (\":) in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

> \":640641123921704,\"logPostDate\":0,\"page\":1,\"searchSuggestions\":[],\"allBlogPosts\":[],\"matchedBlogPosts\":[],\"postListWillLoad\":false,\"requestUrl\":\"\u002Fs\u002Ftehran\u002Fbuy-apartment\",\"dataWillFetch\":false,\"dataWillRefresh\":false,\"errors\"

How can I find 640641123921704 with RegEx in python?

Comment: This is _JSON_ content, not regular text, and you should _not_ be using regex to parse it.  Use Python's `json` library instead.  Please include the full JSON and someone can help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the backslashes really in the data? Assuming that they are...

The pattern `\":(\d+)` will match any sequence of digits following `\":`. Be sure to use a raw string when defining the pattern so that the backslash is not processed: `r'\":(\d+)'`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = r'\":640641123921704,\"logPostDate\":0,\"page\":1,\"searchSuggestions\":[],\"allBlogPosts\":[],\"matchedBlogPosts\":[],\"postListWillLoad\":false,\"requestUrl\":\"\u002Fs\u002Ftehran\u002Fbuy-apartment\",\"dataWillFetch\":false,\"dataWillRefresh\":false,\"errors\"'

>>> re.findall(r'\":(\d+)', text)
['640641123921704', '0', '1']
```

As a side note, the data seems to be in JSON format. Regular expressions might not be the best way to process it. Check out the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
text = '''\":640641123921704,\"logPostDate\":0,\"page\":1,\"searchSuggestions\":[],\"allBlogPosts\":[],\"matchedBlogPosts\":[],\"postListWillLoad\":false,\"requestUrl\":\"\u002Fs\u002Ftehran\u002Fbuy-apartment\",\"dataWillFetch\":false,\"dataWillRefresh\":false,\"errors\"'''

pattern = re.compile(r'\":(\d+)')
pattern.findall(text)
```